# Changing colors for within-community edges in igraph

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, edges

Hej everyone.
The igraph manual points that the default values for edge.color are green for the edges within communities and red for between communities. 
Is there a way to change these defaults and pass other arguments?

```
    > net
    IGRAPH UNW- 11 18 -- 
    + attr: name (v/c), media (v/c), media.type (v/n), type.label,
    (v/c), audience.size (v/n), weight (e/n), type
    | (e/c)
    + edges (vertex names):
    [1] s04--s11 s08--s09 s08--s09 s09--s10 s07--s08 s07--s08 s07--s10                
    s12--s13 s12--s14 s13--s14 s12--s13 s05--s09 s04--s06
    [14] s04--s12 s06--s06 s11--s14 s06--s12 s07--s14
    > V(net)
    + 11/11 vertices, named:
    [1] s04 s05 s06 s07 s08 s09 s10 s11 s12 s13 s14

    > E(net)
    + 18/18 edges (vertex names):
    [1] s04--s11 s08--s09 s08--s09 s09--s10 s07--s08 s07--s08 s07--s10         
    s12--s13 s12--s14 s13--s14 s12--s13 s05--s09 s04--s06
    [14] s04--s12 s06--s06 s11--s14 s06--s12 s07--s14

    > cwt <- cluster_walktrap(net)

    > plot(cwt,net,vertex.label.cex=0.8)
```

In this example, I would like to change the edge s07--s14 to green, and those from s11 and s04 to the red module (s14,s12,s06) in purple:
[Graph.Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLzEa.png)

Also, where is this information stored? 
Objects of class "communities" only have lists with the community vertex members, but nothing on the edges.

Cheers,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [MCVE]